# simple GUI addon to existing win console app

Tags: c++, user-interface

I've always been developing simple(console) apps. And even then most problems I had was with starting/porting/CMaking/ libraries to work. 
I need to find a gui which is added/used by adding #include "somelibrary.h" to EXISTING c++ project. I've downloaded QT, but it seems I have to create a new QTproject,... and thought alone of including all CUDA,OpenCV,others is making me sick. 
I've been experimenting with windows forms (.net?) but there is this managed/unmanaged border with its creepy bugs. 
So I'd like to add GUI to existing project (where forms can be designed in completely separate designer).
Do you know any? 
Or maybe You'd suggest me different approach?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) and [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com). CMake is better than qmake to manage projects and use additional libraries. Currently Qt is the best multi-platform GUI API.

Answer (score 1):

QT and winforms can be added on to an existing project but it's harder that taking a gui application and adding your project to it. Event driven code is organized differently than procedural code.

You don't need CUDA or OpenCV for a GUI.

Comment: I know - but GUI is useful for OpenCV or CUDA :) 
So if you're saying it's even harder to add QT to existing project... :(